# how to Display Hex data instead of text?

Tags: c++, hex, polling

I am using serial programming to communicate with a GPS device I am using a binary protocol to communicate with it. it works in such a way that when writing to the device I receive a stream of data every 1 second. my problem is that when I poll this data and print it out I receiver the ASCII characters instead of the HEX data. I need to see the hex data so I could parse it. this is the code I wrote

```
  int Open_UBX()
{
  unsigned char PollPOSLLH[11] = {0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x01,0x0E,0x47};
  write(fd,&PollPOSLLH,11);
  }

  int   main(){
Open_UBX();
              while (c!='q')
            {
                   if (read(fd,&data,1)>0) 
                      {
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&data,1);   // if new data is available on the serial port, print it out


                    }

               if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&c,1)>0)  
                  {

                    write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1);    // if new data is available on the console, send it to the serial port

                  }
        }
        close(fd);
 return(0);
}
```

ofcourse the port is open and the settings are configured but my problem is the data doesn't appear hex so I can't parse it I only get characters that I don't understand

Answer (score 5):

You can use std::hex. Here is a small example :

```
int number = 23;
std::cout << std::hex << number << std::endl;
//result is 17
```

EDIT :
After thinking on it a little more, I recalled that std::hex sets a flag, so all numbers you print after using it for one time will be printed in hexadecimal format. To revert to decimal use std::dec.
Example :

```
int number = 23;
std::cout << std::hex << number << std::endl; //17
std::cout << number << std::endl; //also 17
std::cout << std::dec << number << std::endl; //23
```